# I want to overwrite value in field input with default attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to enter my numeric value in input with currency. The field has a default attribute of 0.00.

this command does not change anything:

```
webElement.clear();
System.out.println("webElement.getAttribute("value")); //0,00
```

When I try to register my value equal to 803 in it, the field eventually gets a value of 0.00803, which is then rounded to 0.01:

```
webElement.sendKeys(text);
System.out.println("webElement.getAttribute("value")); //0,008003
```

The same thing happens when I use this command:

```
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a", text)); //0,008003
```

Environment:

- mac os
- selenium-java-3
- guava-25.0-jre
- java 8
- Google Chrome 77 version
- ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `executeScript()` method from `JavascriptExecutor` as below :

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter the xpath here")); // you can use any locator
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='enter the value here';", element);
```